# Why does scrollview fills the gap at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, safeareaview

I have been issues with the `ScrollView` when I combined it with `SafeAreaView`. It leaves some gaps at the bottom. I also tried moving ScrollView from outside of SafeAreaView (after removing `flex`, `flexGrow` from SafeAreaView), but the SafeAreaView is taking up too much space on top (see the second image). How can I let ScrollView to take whole empty space? Bear in mind that `Text` to explain the gap will be removed.

```
import React from "react";
import { ScrollView, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const ScrollViewPage = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#EFF0F3",
          flex: 1,
          flexGrow: 1,
          borderWidth: 3,
          borderColor: "red",
        }}
      >
        <ScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            flex: 1,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: "blue",
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              borderWidth: 1,
              flex: 1,

              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text>Hello</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <Text>Why doesn't the scrollview fill here?</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of the issue]

The second image:

[image: The Second Image]

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot it imagine pure html. Your Scrollview is probably wrapped in a div of sorts. so for example

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 
  <!-- ======= Header would typically go here ======= -->
  <header>
      <!-- ======= NavBar would typically go here ======= -->
      <navbar>
      </navbar>
  <header/>
  <!-- ======= Now the Content and your ScrollView would go here======= -->
  <!-- ===When React renders your code looks like this probably======= -->
  <div>
   <ScrollView>
   </ScrollView>
  </div>
  <!-- ===This is going to make your ScrollView take the shape of parent======= -->
</body>

</html>
```

In react when you are calling components sometimes it gets automatically wrapped and takes the size of it's parent. ScrollViewPAge would be the parent in this case. You will need to set the size of that container.  Can you share what the source looks like after it renders?
especially using <> as a place holder. If you try wrapping everything in a div do you get different results?  I would also try absolute values for fun to see if you get closer. If you do there is a parent you have out there.

Comment: Just FYI: this is React Native. How can I see the source?

Comment: so with debugging you can do https://reactnative.dev/docs/react-devtools. Then i would also try wrapping all your code in a <View></View> and style it to 100% but again using react-devtools will give you html like code that will tell you contraints, sizes, etc

Comment: I did it, but I can't see any "additional" attributes on ScrollView. https://ibb.co/XSKvYsv. Also, nothing is wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove unnecessary properties from SafeAreaView style.
2. Remove unnecessary properties from ScrollView contentContainerStyle.
3. Remove the extra View that wraps the Text component.

Here is the updated code

```
import React from "react";
import { ScrollView, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const ScrollViewPage = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#EFF0F3",
        }}
      >
        <ScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text>Hello</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default ScrollViewPage;
```

Comment: Hi Waseem. Did you try putting `borderWidth` to ScrollView? It does show you the gap that I am talking about. Here is the screenshot - https://ibb.co/MD9WY46

Comment: Hi @Baskaya Absolutely, I experimented with applying borderWidth to the ScrollView, and indeed, it revealed the gap you mentioned. However, after some investigation, I found that the culprit behind this unexpected space is the SafeAreaView. As stated in the React Native documentation, "SafeAreaView renders nested content and automatically applies padding to reflect the portion of the view that is not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, and other ancestor views."

Comment: Thanks, but your solution is still giving me the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SafeAreaView, you can use useSafeAreaInsets() from 'react-native-safe-area-context' hook to get the insets and apply the padding only on the top of your ScrollView which should solve your use case.

Here's how I did it:

```js
import { ScrollView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export const ScrollViewPage = (props) => {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  // You can check the inset values of top,bottom, left & right here
  console.log(insets);

  return (
    <>
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          flex: 1,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: 'blue',
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
        style={{ paddingTop: insets.top }}>
        <View
          style={{
            borderWidth: 1,
            flex: 1,

            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <Text>Why doesn't the scrollview fill here?</Text>
    </>
  );
};
```

For reference, you can check the snack [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@danglingcoder/scrollview-question)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason would be missing style prop in ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
 style={{flex: 1}}
 contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
>
 ...
</ScrollView>
```